# fork() is returning a number greater than 0

Tags: c, unix, fork

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
// Curtis    
void kloop(int x)
{
    int breakCondition;
    breakCondition = 0;
    while(1)
    {
            printf("Process %d running\n", x);
            sleep(1);

            breakCondition = breakCondition + 1;
            if (breakCondition == 5)
            {
                    break;
            }
    }
}
```

//---------------

```
void makeChild()
{
    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    printf("fork number %d\n", pid);
    printf("processid: %d", getpid());

    if (pid < 0)
    {
            printf("You done messed up.\n");
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
            printf("You are in child process %d\n", getpid());
    }
    else
    {
            printf("You ain't no kid.\n");
    }

    printf("fork number after if/else:  %d\n", pid);
    printf("processid after if/else:  %d\n", getpid());
}
```

//---------------

```
int main()
{
    int status;
    int n;
    printf("How many child processes do you want to create?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("\n");

    kloop(n);

    int i;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
            //printf("\t'i' at %d", i);
            makeChild();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is a .c file and I'm using gcc and ./a.out to run it in the terminal.
When I've used fork before, it usually gives me a value equal to 0 or less.
In this case, it looks like a processid.

Here is an example of an output:

How many child processes do you want to create?

1

Process 1 running

Process 1 running

Process 1 running

Process 1 running

Process 1 running

fork number 10572

processid: 10566You ain't no kid.

fork number after if/else:  10572

processid after if/else:  10566

fork number 0

processid: 10572You are in child process 10572

fork number after if/else:  0

processid after if/else:  10572

Comment: `fork()` returns 0 to the child process and the child's PID to the parent process.

Comment: So in my makeChild() function, because fork() returns 0 to the child process and the child's PID to the parent process, both the 'else if' block and the 'else' block will execute every time? This is essentially two programs -- a child process that has the 'else if' run and a parent process where the 'else' runs, right?

Comment: Yes, one will execute to the child, and the other to the parent.

Comment: If I only wanted to interact with the child processes, I could essentially just remove the 'else' statement? Thanks btw. Is there a way to upvote you?

Comment: I guess. When you fork a process they both continue running exactly from the last operation you called which was the `fork()` syscall, the only difference is the syscall's return value. So you use it's return value to determine who does what. The child process will continue to run the loop where it creates more children if you let it, so you probably shouldn't nest the `fork()` call within another function. Make it so that if `fork()` returns 0, you abort the loop.

Comment: If `fork` returns <0, it does not indicate a user error.  It indicates (probably) that there is a resource issue.  "You done messed up" is not a relevant message.

Comment: @Havenard, I had it looped because I'm in the process of creating a child process once for every second and deleting the child processes every five seconds in the order that they were created.

Comment: the posted code has all 3 return conditions from `fork()` executing the same code (after the if/else sequence)  This is a BAD idea.  The error return should call `perror()` then `exit()`  the child return should (after the call to `printf()`) call `exit()`  the parent return should (after the call to `printf()`)  call `wait()` or `waitpid()` then it can safely exit the program.  The parent not calling `wait()` or `waitpid()` is a good way to create a zombie process

Answer (score 0):

The basic pattern of using `fork` is this.

```
void makeChild() {
    pid_t pid = fork();

    // Error
    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    // Child
    else if (pid == 0) {
        printf("Child, pid %d, ppid %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

        doSomething();

        // This is the important piece, the child branch must exit.
        exit(0);
    }
    // Parent
    else {
        printf("Parent, pid %d. Child pid is %d\n", getpid(), pid);
    }
}
```

Processing continues after the `fork` for both the parent and child. The only difference is what the parent and child receive. The child receives 0, the parent receives the pid of the child.

```
$ ./test
Parent, pid 35324. Child pid is 35325
Child, pid 35325, ppid 35324
```

The critical thing is once the child is done doing whatever it's doing ***the child branch must exit*** else it will continue along and run the rest of the code.

Comment: this is missing the call (in the parent process) to `wait()` or `waitpid()` so the parent waits until the child exits before exiting